# Detecting action bar icon long press

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to detect long press on application's icon in the ActionBar in Android application. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add custom view to action bar

```
    View view     = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.actionbar,null);
    btnClose    = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
    btnClose.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Log.d("rvg", "Long click:");
            return false;
        }
    });



  getSupportActionBar() . setCustomView(view);
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately standard android tools doesn't provide such possibility.

The only possible way is to create your own actionLayout, see `android:actionLayout`

I think, this question is very similar to
[Android ActionBar options long click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9261329/android-actionbar-options-long-click-event)