# Android Menu item's tool-tip in the ToolBar doesn't work properly

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

From the action bar documentation:

> If the action item appears with only the icon, a user can long-press the item to reveal a tool-tip that displays the action item's title. The android:icon is always optional, but recommended.

But Android Menu item's  tool-tip in the ToolBar doesn't work properly in my case.

This is what I have in styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Actionbar color -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <!--Status bar color-->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <!--Window color-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>

    <!--drawerArrowStyle-->
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    <!--Activity enter and exit animation-->
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/TranslateEnterExitAnimation</item>

    <!--<item name="colorAccent">#EC9290</item>-->
    <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/CursorColor</item>
</style>
```

And My ToolBar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />
```

And menu_feedback.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_action_send"
    android:title="@string/send_text"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_actionbar_send"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

I get this on HTC devices, PS: Nexus 5 is ok.
[image]

But the normal toast is ok.
[image]

So, is there an elegant solution to make the tool-tip work properly? thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i solved the problem as follows.

First, Customizing ActionMenuItemView which using

`final Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();`

instead of

`final Context context = getContext();`

to show a Toast like below.

```
public class ActionMenuItemView extends android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView{
public ActionMenuItemView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public ActionMenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public ActionMenuItemView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (hasText()) {
        // Don't show the cheat sheet for items that already show text.
        return false;
    }

    final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
    final Rect displayFrame = new Rect();
    getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
    getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(displayFrame);

    final Context context = getContext().getApplicationContext();
    final int width = getWidth();
    final int height = getHeight();
    final int midy = screenPos[1] + height / 2;
    int referenceX = screenPos[0] + width / 2;
    if (ViewCompat.getLayoutDirection(v) == ViewCompat.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR) {
        final int screenWidth = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
        referenceX = screenWidth - referenceX; // mirror
    }
    Toast cheatSheet = Toast.makeText(context, getItemData().getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    if (midy < displayFrame.height()) {
        // Show along the top; follow action buttons
        cheatSheet.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | GravityCompat.END, referenceX, height);
    } else {
        // Show along the bottom center
        cheatSheet.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, height);
    }
    cheatSheet.show();
    return false;
}}
```

Second, create abc_action_menu_item_layout.xml and place it in layout folder instead of abc_action_menu_item_layout.xml in support-v7 library.

```
<com.example.widget.ActionMenuItemView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="4dip"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="8dip"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/actionMenuTextAppearance"
    android:textColor="?attr/actionMenuTextColor"
    style="?attr/actionButtonStyle"/>
```

It works like a charm although i don't know the difference between **getContext().getApplicationContext()** and **getContext()** in the ActionMenuItemView.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can override the default behavior with ease, but as for a work-around you can create your own items [as hinted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9261497/1576010), and then you will be able to set up listeners for you own items, and [show toast under the items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21026786/show-toast-widget-underneath-a-view/21026866#21026866) on long press events.

Comment: Yes, i also found the custom action view tool-tip, but i have many Activities with MenuItems, it's a lot of work in this way, thanks Campiador.